# Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit

Tags: rinkeby

Being a noob on eth dev, I have deployed hardhat's sample greeter contract into reikeby network but when I try to fetch the greeting I get this Error in the console:

```
inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: execution reverted {code: -32000, message: 'execution reverted'}
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:17
_runReturnHandlers @ inpage.js:17
_processRequest @ inpage.js:17
await in _processRequest (async)
_handle @ inpage.js:17
handle @ inpage.js:17
_rpcRequest @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
request @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ web3-provider.ts:96
send @ web3-provider.ts:169
(anonymous) @ json-rpc-provider.ts:560
(anonymous) @ json-rpc-provider.ts:1
__awaiter @ json-rpc-provider.ts:1
perform @ json-rpc-provider.ts:535
(anonymous) @ base-provider.ts:1425
fulfilled @ base-provider.ts:1
Promise.then (async)
step @ base-provider.ts:1
fulfilled @ base-provider.ts:1
Promise.then (async)
step @ base-provider.ts:1
(anonymous) @ base-provider.ts:1
__awaiter @ base-provider.ts:1
call @ base-provider.ts:1418
(anonymous) @ index.ts:389
fulfilled @ index.ts:1
Promise.then (async)
step @ index.ts:1
(anonymous) @ index.ts:1
__awaiter @ index.ts:1
(anonymous) @ index.ts:370
fetchGreeting @ App.js:23
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:8299
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22396
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22413
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
App.js:26 Error:  Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"code":-32000,"message":"execution reverted"}, method="call", transaction={"to":"0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3","data":"0xcfae3217","accessList":null}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.5.2)
    at Logger.makeError (index.ts:225:1)
    at Logger.throwError (index.ts:237:1)
    at checkError (json-rpc-provider.ts:80:1)
    at Web3Provider.<anonymous> (json-rpc-provider.ts:562:1)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (json-rpc-provider.ts:1:1)
```

I've deployed the contract using hardhat and connecting to Rinkeby using alchemy link `https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/myappskey` here is the configs:

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  paths: {
    artifacts: './src/artifacts',
  },
  network: {
    // hardhat:{
    //   chainId: 1337
    // },
    rinkeby: {
      url: secret.url,
      accounts: secret.key,
      gas: 2100000,
      gasPrice: 8000000000
    }
    
  }
};
```

I have no issues deploying the same contract on the localhost node.
I'm wondering what is wrong here and how can I fix it?